# Material Dashboard not showing up inside the Navigation Schematic when using routerLink in Angular 7

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-schematics

Hi I am trying to add a Navigation Schematic in my project in which the first link will show the dashboard, so when the page is displayed first it should show the dashboard. Later I will add additional links.
The issue is when I try to add the Dashboard component using routerLink inside the Navigation Schematic link it never displays the Dashboard. However when I call the dashboard component directly inside my app.component.html it displays the dashboard correctly.

Please note the exact same way works and displays the dashboard in Angular 6

I have tried all possible combinations for routerLink but it does not work

Here is how I have configured app.module.ts

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { LayoutModule } from '@angular/cdk/layout';
import { MatToolbarModule, MatButtonModule, MatSidenavModule, MatIconModule, MatListModule, MatGridListModule, MatCardModule, MatMenuModule, MatTableModule, MatPaginatorModule, MatSortModule } from '@angular/material';
import { AdminConsoleNavComponent } from './admin-console-nav/admin-console-nav.component';
import { AdminConsoleDashboardComponent } from './admin-console-dashboard/admin-console-dashboard.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: AdminConsoleDashboardComponent }  
]

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AdminConsoleNavComponent,
    AdminConsoleDashboardComponent        
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    LayoutModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
    MatTableModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatSortModule    
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

My Navigation Component html looks like this

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
  <mat-sidenav
    #drawer
    class="sidenav"
    fixedInViewport="true"
    [attr.role]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'dialog' : 'navigation'"
    [mode]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'over' : 'side'"
    [opened]="!(isHandset$ | async)">
    <mat-toolbar color="primary">Menu</mat-toolbar>
    <mat-nav-list>
        <a mat-list-item routerLink = "/">Dashboard</a>
      <a mat-list-item href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a mat-list-item href="#">Link 3</a>
    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <mat-toolbar color="primary">
      <button
        type="button"
        aria-label="Toggle sidenav"
        mat-icon-button
        (click)="drawer.toggle()"
        *ngIf="isHandset$ | async">
        <mat-icon aria-label="Side nav toggle icon">menu</mat-icon>
      </button>
      <span>mock-admin-console</span>
    </mat-toolbar>
    <!-- Add Content Here -->
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

Inside the 
app.component.html

```
<app-admin-console-nav>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</app-admin-console-nav>
```

Expected Result - Dashboard should show up with Nav Menu as the path given is '' and it should default to the Dashboard

Actual Result - The Nav Menu Shows up but not the dashboard. when I click on the link nothing happens

Comment: Alright, guys, I resolved the issue. So anybody who encounters the same in the future, just remember to add the dashboard component name in the Nav bar html where it is written  </mat-toolbar>
    <!-- Add Content Here -->
  </mat-sidenav-content>   So replace "add content here" with <DashboardComp></DashboardComp> or ng-Content will also work. Sometimes the simple things appear the hardest to do. But anyways now  you know.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the following tag under Add Content Here :

```
<ng-content></ng-content>
```